# I can' contrive a scenario where what is stated in this text is logical

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The text (from [a NY Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/12/13/books/oxford-cocktails-spirits-david-wondrich-noah-rothbaum.html)) is:

> These passages will allow you to convince yourself, and perhaps even your spouse, that your interest in getting wasted is an academic pursuit.

Although I have been reading the NY Times for over a year now to practice my English this matter seemed like the first day. Too many unknown words to read through even using a dictionary.

So if someone can help me and tell in what sense this text makes possible a book convince any one the ones interest in getting wasted is an academic pursuit???

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you asking about the content of the passages themselves (which you haven't included or linked to) or about the definition of particular words in that sentence?

Comment: @Katy, sorry for having poorly assembled this question. The link is: "https://www.nytimes.com/2021/12/13/books/oxford-cocktails-spirits-david-wondrich-noah-rothbaum.html" by read the headline what I get from is that everyone who has  interest in getting wasted is in an academic pursuit. and I can't see that being truth.

Comment: Thanks for the source. Again, please edit to highlight exactly what you don't understand. For instance, you would need to know that "getting wasted" means getting drunk (or otherwise impaired, but this is a review of a book about cocktails), that "academic pursuit" can mean not just "studying something in school" but [approaching a topic in a systematic and scholarly way](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/academic-pursuit).

Comment: The preceding paragraph helps make it clearer: "Some of the material in “The Oxford Companion to Spirits and Cocktails” is relatively heavy going. ... The vagaries of distillation cover nine pages. Long and sometimes sleepy essays cover the world region by region." That's a lot of analytical, quasi-scientific detail. In light of that, the next sentence could be paraphrased "Even though you enjoy getting drunk, you could convince yourself and your spouse that you're really engaging in research and analysis."

Comment: @Andy Bonner, thanks for the attention, my point is the headline is generalizated and made think the mentioned book can convince anyone that the reason anyone in the world drinks is because one is in an academic pursuit Meaning the only reason one is drinking is because is in an academic pursuit get it?

Comment: Also, note you have not told us the headline, and it's been changed since I saw it this morning (if I remember, it *was* "Your interest in getting wasted is an academic pursuit"). Headlines are often impossible to make sense of on their own, and don't represent the whole article (for one thing, they're written by different people; my dad was a newspaper reporter and often complained about the headlines written for his articles). In this case they pulled out a funny sentence from the article because it catches our attention, *because* you have to read the article to see how it could make sense.

Comment: Note also that the actual sentence from the article is using humor and irony. It suggests that you might "convince yourself," which implies that you have your doubts. Overall, its tone suggests more that your interest is *not* (wholly) academic than that it is.

Comment: @AndyBonner - having got around the NYT paywall by a secret method, I realised I had forgotten just how American it really is: "Among the things this book admires: Laird’s Bonded Apple Brandy; using dense, very cold ice; knowing how to “spank” **an** herbal garnish; "

Comment: @EulerHenry - you have to consider the sentence in its **wider context**. An NYT review of a book from an academic publisher (Oxford University Press) about a topic not generally seen as scholarly. It is not surprising that the review, like the book itself, contains elements of levity.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that this is an example of irony.  It is meant to be ridiculous, and so funny.

It is not meant to be understood literally.

It imagines, humorously that you will have a conversation like this with your spouse:

> *Spouse*: Why are you drunk again!?
> *You*: (drunkenly) I am *not* drunk! Thish ish a sherious schientfic shtudy of the merits of apple brandy over bourbon wishkey.  Itsh all exshplained in thish book.
> *Spouse*: Let me see that book! Hmm how interesting. I want to help with your investigation. Please pour me a double.

This is ridiculous, which is why it is funny.

The headline claims this book allows you to convince yourself of something that you know isn't true - that is ridiculous, and so funny.

The headline makes a humerous comment about the relationship between spouses. Your spouse is likely to be unhappy about you getting drunk. The headline claims that this book could make him/her think it is okay.  That is ridiculous, and so it is funny.